# iDB2 Select command with parameters returning SQL0418

Tags: c#, sql, .net, db2

I'm developing a .NET application that connects to a DB2 iSeries 7.1 database, using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll.

I need to do a SELECT command that has n parameters which are defined in the query as `@paramX`, setting the parameter values afterwards, but when I run the code I get a `SQL048 Use of parameter marker not valid.`. I've searched everywhere for documentation / examples but everything I've read is in par with the code I'm using. Am I missing something? If this is not valid, what is the best alternative?

This is the isolated code I'm using to test.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String myConnectionString = "DataSource=*******;Database=*******;UserId=*******;Password=*******;";
        iDB2Connection myConnection = new iDB2Connection();
        try{
            myConnection.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
            myConnection.Open();

            var cmd = new iDB2Command("SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE(@param0),TIME(@param1)) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1", myConnection);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new iDB2Parameter("@param0", iDB2DbType.iDB2Char));
            cmd.Parameters["@param0"].Value = "1900-01-01";

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new iDB2Parameter("@param1", iDB2DbType.iDB2Char));
            cmd.Parameters["@param1"].Value = "00.00.00";

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(reader[i].ToString().Trim());
                    }

                    Console.Out.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }finally{
            if (myConnection != null)
            {
                myConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
```

## EDIT

In an unrelated answer I've found that the problem might be that DB2 doesn't know the underlying type of the parameter (which is strange since I'm strong typing it), thus, a possible solution is to do a cast in the query to the expected param type, as such:

`SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE(cast(@param0 as char(10))),TIME(cast(@param1 as char(10)))) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

This actually worked but, isn't there any better way to handle this?

Comment: Why not just cast it to the proper data type... `SELECT CAST(@param1 AS DATE), CAST(@param2 AS TIME) ...` ?

Comment: Is there not a `iDB2DbType.iDB2Timestamp` type you could use?  Then you wouldn't have to cast at all...

Comment: @bhamby The answer I mentioned only referenced char but I did that afterwards. That being said, it still requires the cast.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm sure there is, but, the params aren't Timestamps, they are DATE and TIME, respectively, in string format, is there a reason why that would work? (can't test it right now)

Comment: @vvolkgang - Except the first thing you do is create a timestamp with it, so why not just skip a step and give the thing a timestamp in the first place?  Currently the _parameters_ aren't date/time either - they're string, which you're telling the db to convert afterwards.  Save yourself some hassle and actually pass the correct object type (that is, a C# `datetime`, to a properly typed parameter).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You're right but, this isolated example is reflecting the workflow that I have in a system I don't have access to, i.e., I can't change the params I receive and can't manipulate the information that they are going to haver afterwards. I was just making sure that this was actually a DB2 platform/driver block. 

I'm going to answer and close this with the info I already have, thank you for your input !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, this is a platform limitation. that can be confirmed by an explanation that the platform adds to the application exception*. That being said, as I can't change the parameters I receive and don't have access to the info they are going to held in the query, the best solution to my specific problem is to do a **CAST** to the types that the **TIMESTAMP** scalar function uses, e.g.:

`SELECT TIMESTAMP(cast(@param0 as DATE),cast(@param1 as TIME)) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`